# Need help producing a span tag for every group_concat() item. mySql, VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, mysql, vb.net, outer-join, group-concat

I currently have a sql select statement that selects several things from 3 different tables at the moment, here is that code:

```
SELECT
group_concat(w.event) as events, group_concat(w.date) as dates, 
group_concat(a.time) as times, group_concat(DISTINCT w.tmc) as tmcs, 
group_concat(a.weather) as weathers, group_concat(a.surface_temperature) as temperatures, p.top, p.LEFT, w.City 
FROM weather w 
LEFT OUTER JOIN application a ON a.DATE = w.DATE AND a.tmc = w.tmc 
LEFT OUTER JOIN pinlocations p ON w.city = p.cityname 
WHERE  w.DATE = '" & datepicker_value.Text & "' 
AND w.event= '" & weatherType.SelectedItem.Value & "' GROUP BY p.top, p.left
```

I'm using the following repeater to display it on a map:

```
<asp:Repeater id="weatherFeed" Runat="server"><ItemTemplate>
    <a href="index.htm" onClick="return hs.htmlExpand(this)">
    <img src="images/mapPin.png" title="<%#Container.DataItem("city")%>"
        style="position:absolute; left:<%#Container.DataItem("left")%>px; 
        top:<%#Container.DataItem("top")%>px;" /></a>

        <div class="highslide-maincontent">
    Title: <%#Container.DataItem("City")%><br />
        TMC: <%#Container.DataItem("tmcs")%><br />
        Location on the map: <%#Container.DataItem("left")%>, <%#Container.DataItem("top")%><br />
        <div class="span-1">Time</div><div class="span-1">Surface Temperatures</div>
        <div class="span-1"><%#Container.DataItem("temperatures")%>&deg;</div><div 
        class="span-1"><%#Container.DataItem("times")%></div>
        </div> 
</ItemTemplate></asp:Repeater>
```

The issue I'm having is this, I want the  to be produced for every temperature and every time. Currently its putting all the temperatures in 1 div and all the time in 1 div, this is because i'm using group_concat(). If I remove group_concat() from the time/surface temperature then I only get the first row containing data based off my select statement. How can I tweak my sql statement so I can produce the following outcome:

```
Title: Indianapolis
TMC: 107+4652
Location on the Map: 250, 347
<div class="span-1">Time:</div>    <div class="span-1">Surface Temp:</div> 
<div class="span-1">1:00     <div class="span-1">31deg</div> 
<div class="span-1">2:00     <div class="span-1">36deg</div> 
<div class="span-1">3:00     <div class="span-1">42deg</div>
```

Greatly Appreciated!

Comment: This code will be vulnerable to sql injection

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT
  p.top, p.LEFT, w.City
  , w.tmc
  , group_concat(w.event) as events
  , group_concat(w.date) as dates
  , group_concat(CONCAT('<div class="span-1">',a.time
                        ,<div class="span-1">, A.surface_temperature)
                 , SEPARATOR '</div>') as divspan
  , group_concat(a.weather) as weathers

FROM weather w 
LEFT JOIN application a ON (a.DATE = w.DATE AND a.tmc = w.tmc) 
LEFT JOIN pinlocations p ON (w.city = p.cityname) 
WHERE w.DATE = '" & datepicker_value.Text & "' 
      AND w.event= '" & weatherType.SelectedItem.Value & "' 
GROUP BY p.top, p.left, w.tmc
```

All the fields you want to be distinct you put in the `group by` part.
Al the values not uniquely defined by the `group by` goes into a `group_concat`

You will need to edit this line:

```
 , group_concat(CONCAT(...
```

a bit to get things right, see:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: I don't believe so. My issue is I want to make it so every surface_temperature and every time are put into their own div tag. Both my method and your method put all the surface temperatures in 1 div tag and all the times in 1 div tag.

I'm getting this:

<div class="span-1">1:00,2:00,3:00</div><div class="span-1">31deg,36deg,42deg</div>